# cannot open camera "0" without camera permission

Tags: java, android-camera, android-permissions

I have the following in my manifest

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
```

however I receive this error

```
An error occurred while connecting to camera 0: Status(-8, EX_SERVICE_SPECIFIC): '1: validateClientPermissionsLocked:1165: Caller ... (PID 10153, UID 6049) cannot open camera "0" without camera permission'
```

I am attempting to get a camera working using this code

```
public static Camera getCameraInstance(){
    Camera c = null;
    try {
        c = Camera.open();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("getCameraInstance", "exception", e);
    }
    return c; // returns null if camera is unavailable
}
```

How do I get this camera working?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Need to enable permissions at runtime. The above error is outputted when the 0 indexed camera does not have permissions. Adding permissions to the manifest is not what enables it on the phone... the below code will.

```java
    public static void checkCameraPermissions(Context context){
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
        {
            // Permission is not granted
            Log.d("checkCameraPermissions", "No Camera Permissions");
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity) context,
                    new String[] { Manifest.permission.CAMERA },
                    100);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hey, code only answers aren't the norm around here. Perhaps you could add some verbiage around it, explaining what the OP has done wrong and how this code fixes it?

Comment: @SoftwareEngineer Done!